# A very basic XPath error

Tags: xml, xpath

I am using http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php
as an online XPath evaluator. I tried a few others but it's all the same

I have the following in my xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test xmlns="abc">
</test>
```

Now the XPath queries

```
/
.
```

gives me the output :-

```
<test xmlns="abc">
</test>
```

However, the queries

```
test
/test
//test
```

Do not give me any output at all. I'm doing a very basic mistake but I can't figure out what. I think it's got something to do with namespaces but changing the queries to

```
abc:test
```

doesn't help either because it gives an Invalid Expression error.

I'm using http://www.w3schools.com/xpath http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathtutorial.php &
http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html

as my sources for XPath tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no explicit namespace prefixes in your target file, but you still need to cater for them. You can write

```
/*[local-name()='test' and namespace-uri()='abc']
```

Your "abc" is a namespaceURI, not a namespace prefix. It is probably invalid as most tools will test it for a URI form such as

```
http://www.abc.com/
```

A better file would be:

```
<test xmlns="http://www.abc.com">
</test>
```

when your query would be:

```
/*[local-name()='test' and namespace-uri()='http://www.abc.com/']
```

I have tested this on your site and it works.

The form

```
abc:test
```

will depend on a mechanism to set the prefix `abc` to `'http://www.abc.com/'` and there doesn't seem to be a mechanism on the site

Comment: are you sure if it works? I tried to copy paste your code exactly and it still gives me null results.

Comment: I retried it and it failed and I retried and it worked. The query `/*[local-name()='test' and namespace-uri()='http://www.abc.com']` and the xml `<test xmlns="http://www.abc.com"></test>` worked just now

Comment: also try the simpler query `/*[local-name()='test' and namespace-uri()='http://www.abc.com']` if you know there are no other namespaces

Comment: I think the copy and paste has lost a whitespace. Should be OK now

Comment: uhh... i don't see the difference between the 'simpler query' and the first one you just posted. Anyways, I think I get the point... thanks

Comment: You MIGHT have two elements "test" from different namespaces and the simpler query would match both.